# How would I get a function to run every 24 hours on a server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I am using this code to make it run 24 hours after the program is executed but how do I make it run automatically on lets say heroku or something like this? How would I need to change the code?

```
 setInterval(myFunction, 1000*60*60*24)
```

Thanks!

Edit: I launched this exact code onto heroku as a web worker and it's been running once every 24 hours, just as I wanted. Nothing extra was needed.

Comment: you need to create a page where you execute the function and put that page in cron and set the time every 24 hours.

Answer (score 6):

For this you can use node scheduler npm package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

node scheduler  allows you to schedule functions for execution at specific dates, with optional recurrence rules.

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 * * *', function(){
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

Above code will execute a cron job when the minute is 0 and hour is 0. basically every day 0:0 in the mid night

use [this site](https://crontab.guru/) to generate formats for the scheduling

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` will only work if the script is kept running 24hrs a day..
otherwise you will need to set up a cron job to call the script for you 
this might be a good place to start: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800